Put service offline/online using .Net in cluster environment
I have a service running in a cluster environment and need to be able to put it offline and then bring it back online. This service when started also spawns other services and when stopped should stop those services as well.
In a non-clustered scenario it is easy to stop or kill a process. To stop a service I use:
public static void StopService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
    ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);

    if ((service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running)) ||
        (service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)) ||
        (service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Paused)))
    {
        try
        {
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
            service.Stop();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }
}

For killing process tree, I found a sample here.
The problem is, in cluster environment, if you stop/kill a service, it assumes something went wrong and fails over which is not desirable.
How can I offline/online a service managed by cluster failover using .Net/C#?

What kind of cluster are you talking about with what kind of monitoring/health management that would react here?

Failover cluster, there are primary and secondary servers, one active at any given time and services run from active server. If a service managed by cluster failover manager stops, it switches to other server, assuming something had gone wrong.

You remember .Net does not mean Windows also? I assume you are talking about the Windows Server Clustering features. In that case that would be the most relevant info here. This is only a indirect programming language question but more an administration thing then how that stuff works and there might be better suited communities on stackoverflow for that.

You mean there is no way to programatically put a service, that is manged by failover cluster manager,  offline or bring an offline service back online? Similar to what one can do to a regular Windows service by stopping/killing it? As I showed in sample code in my post, I have done this for regular services not managed by failover manager.
